# Disk Utility Crashed whilst creating a Partition and I'm now missing hard drive space

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility

Disk Utility Crashed whilst creating a Partition, and I now have ~100GB missing, which was the amount I had allocated to the new partition.
The new partition didn't get created, and I now have 100GB missing from the Hard drive. I have a 1TB hard drive, and when I go to Disk Utility, it says:

Capacity : 999.35 GB (999,345,127,424 Bytes)
Available : 586.1 GB (586,103,844,864 Bytes)
Used : 310.52 GB (310,524,317,696 Bytes)

Which adds up to about ~900GB. I used terminal to look using `diskutil list`

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            999.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

I tried Repairing Disk in Disk Utility, and as suggested on another thread, booting into Recovery Mode and Repairing Disk there, but neither made a difference. Am I missing 100 GB on my disk?

Comment: It sounds like the partition is there but you need a partition map to see it; this would entail the use of partition mapping software.

Comment: why wouldn't disk utility show the partition?
also, do you know of any software I could use (preferable free)?

Comment: If you open terminal - what does `diskutil list` show for the information on the actual internal drive (which is almost always /dev/disk0 if you have more than one disk mounted)

Comment: @bmike it says: /dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            999.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3